# Pre-Processing of Sentinel-1 data using Python snappy API

Tags: python, api, sentinel-1

While applying 'Apply-Orbit-File' to Sentinel-1 data during preprocessing via python snappy, the following error produced.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    apply_orb_filter(product)
  File "D:\Satya\PyScripts\snappy_v1.py", line 74, in apply_orb_filter
    output = GPF.createProduct('Apply-Orbit-File', parameters, source)
RuntimeError: org.esa.snap.core.gpf.OperatorException: qc.sentinel1.eo.esa.int
```

The code is as follows

```
def do_apply_orbit_file(source):
    print('\tApply orbit file...')
    parameters = HashMap()
    GPF.getDefaultInstance().getOperatorSpiRegistry().loadOperatorSpis()
    parameters.put('Apply-Orbit-File', True)
    parameters.put('polyDegree','3')
    parameters.put('orbitType','Sentinel Precise (Auto Download)')
    parameters.put('continueOnFail','false')
    output = GPF.createProduct('Apply-Orbit-File', parameters, source)
    return output
```

I suspect that I have set 'orbitType' Auto Download in parameters, but my internet is running behind a proxy server. Do I need to set proxy for 'Auto Download' or something else? If I need to set proxy then how do I include in the code?

Comment: Is there any more to the error message (i.e. traceback code) that might show which line of your function the error occurs during?

Comment: @ycartwhelen total error is updated in the question.

Comment: I think Orbit files automatically download from the web site https://qc.sentinel1.eo.esa.int/. May be my code fails to do the same

Comment: Where are your Sentinel tiles located? If they are above 60° of latitude there is no SRTM data, so the algorithm might fail